# How can I color a <hr> without adding any height?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, tags

Okay, so I make a hr and I want to make it black...because grey just won't do.  But then it looks thicker and ruin the whole styling.  Any idea how to change the color but not the height?  I want it to have the same height as before.  I'm using Chrome (browser and computer) if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just play with the border colors

```
hr
{
 border-color: #000000;  
 border-bottom: none;
 border-left: none;
 border-right: none;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's usually better not to use a `hr` if you just want a horizontal line somewhere. `hr` actually has meaning in HTML. It's usually better to place a top or bottom border on an existing element.